# Gunicorn - Where do Unix sockets come from?

Tags: python, django, sockets, unix, gunicorn

I am trying to configure Gunicorn to use Unix socket, but I can't find any documentation on how these sockets are created or how to troubleshoot them.

I am setting up a Django app, and I can successfully launch to http by specifying the port. However, when I try to use a Unix socket:

```
gunicorn myapp.wsgi:application --bind=unix:/appuser/myapp/gunicorn.sock
```

It returns with:

```
[2015-11-21 09:34:21 +0000] [24380] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
[2015-11-21 09:34:21 +0000] [24380] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-11-21 09:34:22 +0000] [24380] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-11-21 09:34:23 +0000] [24380] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-11-21 09:34:24 +0000] [24380] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-11-21 09:34:25 +0000] [24380] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-11-21 09:34:26 +0000] [24380] [ERROR] Can't connect to /appuser/myapp/gunicorn.sock
```

The gunicorn.sock is located right where it is supposed to be, but the file is empty. I can't find any logs or anything. I am using Nginx on an AWS server and have set up all the relevant configurations according to [the docs](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploy.html). I can post my configuration if it has anything to do with this.

How do I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using unix file system sockets. These are not regular files, so they might look empty when inspected with cat.

A peculiarity of unix file system sockets is that they *must not* exist before an application tries to bind for the path. There must neither be a directory, nor a file, nor a socket at that path before binding. You have to remove the socket; when binding, the socket will be created automatically. It must then, when the application terminates, be removed by the application (or a watchdog) before anyone else (including the re-started application) can bind to that path again.

Example:

```
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
>>> s.bind("foo.sock")
# now foo.sock exists
>>> s.close()
# foo.sock still exists
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
>>> s.bind("foo.sock")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
# boom, the socket must be unlinked manually
>>> import os
>>> os.unlink("foo.sock")
>>> s.bind("foo.sock")
>>> s.close()
```

To avoid these issues, I would use nginx with a http-based reverse proxy to the application and bind the application to 127.0.0.1:someport.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! I deleted the existing sock file, but the issue persists. I am able to bind it in the manner that you suggest, but then I have to append the port to the end of my url to see my site. Should I try to fix this and avoid using Unix socket altogether?

Comment: @AdamStarrh If you configured NGINX like in the linked documentation, I’d assume it "just works", aside from the socket issue. What port number do you need to add? And I assume that you are connecting through NGINX to your application, is that correct? (i.e. you point your webbrowser or whatever to the NGINX server, which then forwards the request to your application)

Comment: Yes, Nginx is my reverse proxy. It is configured just like the documentation. I have to add port 8000 to the url to display the site. I am working through how to convert the settings back to TCP to see if that solves it.

Comment: @AdamStarrh How does your NGINX "listen" directives look like? Do they point to port 80 or port 8000?

Comment: Ooh good catch! I never would have figured that out. It is indeed pointing to 80, should I set it to 8000? Neither setting is working for me yet.

Comment: @AdamStarrh No, it should be set to 80, if you want to use 80. I am pretty clueless by now, are you sure you’re using the nginx to connect? Are you still using unix sockets? If not, what TCP port and IP is your application bound to?

Comment: I tore it all down and built it back up again and it seems to be working now. Must've been a typo in something.